# Django: issue with template path for tenant

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, django-settings

I have an app where depending on its category, a tenant is either directed to the app (and templates) at `/dashboard/templates/dashboard` or `/dashboard2/templates/dashboard2`.

somehow, for dashboard2, the app is not found by Django and it tries to find those templates under `dashboard`.

here is a dashboard2/views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class SupplierPage2(LoginRequiredMixin,APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = request.GET.get('search_ress', None)
        print(query)
        context = {}

        #if query and request.method == 'GET':
        Supplier = supplier2.objects.filter(supplier = query)
        print(Supplier)
       
        labels = Item2.objects.filter(fournisseur = query).values_list('reference', flat=True)[:10]
        print(labels)
        default_items = Item2.objects.filter(fournisseur = query).values_list('number_of_sales', flat=True)[:10]
        print(default_items)
        label1s = Item2.objects.filter(fournisseur = query).values_list('reference', flat=True)[:10]
        print(label1s)
        default_item1s = Item2.objects.filter(fournisseur = query).values_list('number_of_orders_placed', flat=True)[:10]
        print(default_item1s)
            
        context.update({'Supplier' : Supplier, 'labels':labels, 'default_items':default_items,'label1s':label1s, 'default_item1s':default_item1s})


        return render(request, 'Supplier2.html',context)
```

and the error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /Supplier2.html
Supplier2.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://uname.website.net/Supplier2.html
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Supplier2.html
```

and the traceback:

```
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/ubuntu/website/dashboard/templates/dashboard/dashboard2/templates/dashboard2/Supplier2.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/ubuntu/website/customers/templates/Supplier2.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/Supplier2.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/ubuntu/website/dashboard/templates/Supplier2.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/ubuntu/website/tenantlogin/templates/Supplier2.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/ubuntu/website/uploadfiles/templates/Supplier2.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_tenants/templates/Supplier2.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/templates/Supplier2.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_tables2/templates/Supplier2.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/ubuntu/website/dashboard2/templates/Supplier2.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/Supplier2.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crispy_forms/templates/Supplier2.html (Source does not exist)
```

when try specifying `/dashboard2/Supplier2.html` I still get the same error in Django:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /Supplier2.html
/dashboard2/Supplier2.html
```

here is what I have in settings.py for templates:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dashboard/templates/dashboard", "dashboard2/templates/dashboard2")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

at this point, I don't know what else to try

Comment: This template path is worng `/home/ubuntu/website/dashboard/templates/dashboard/dashboard2/templates/dashboard2/Supplier2.htmt`
providing Templates settings definition may help.

Comment: just added what I have in settings.py about templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the settings as below:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dashboard/templates/dashboard"), os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"dashboard2/templates/dashboard2")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```